# Invoke application from standard token

Tags: c++, windows

I have two applications - A and B.
B has '***requireAdminstrator***' manifest and I would like to invoke it from application A which is in standard token. UAC is '*Never-Notify*'.

Is it really possible?

I have already tried `CreateProcess` and `CreateProcessWithLogonW` and both return FALSE and GetLastError shows **740** (*The requested operation requires elevation.* )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code can be used for this:

```
  SHELLEXECUTEINFO shExecInfo;
  shExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
  shExecInfo.fMask = NULL;
  shExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
  shExecInfo.lpVerb = L”runas“;
  shExecInfo.lpFile = L”notepad.exe”;
  shExecInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
  shExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
  shExecInfo.nShow = SW_MAXIMIZE;
  shExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
  ShellExecuteEx(&shExecInfo);
```

Reference:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vistacompatteam/2006/09/25/elevate-through-shellexecute/